# VueJS 3 axios data from parent to child

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3

when I pass the data from Parent to Child Component
I wonder why it is not sent empty?
I want to perform Slug Operations, but I could not solve it in any way.

For example;

I want to capture the data coming from the axios data in the child component and take the necessary actions for them, but it is said that this.initialslug value is empty in the child part, that is, at the beginning.

ParentComponent.Vue

```
<template>
 <div class="mx-auto flex flex-col">
  <div>
   <span>title:</span>
   <input type="text" v-model="title">
  </div>
  <div>
   <span>Slug:</span>
   <Child-component :title="title" :initial-slug="slug"/>
  </div>
 </div>
</template>
<script>
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent.vue";

export default {
 name: "Parent",
 data() {
  return {
   title: '',
   slug: ''
  }
 },
 components: {ChildComponent},
 async created() {
  await axios.get(`/categories/4/detail`)
   .then((response) => {
    this.title = response.data.title
    this.slug = response.data.slug
   })
 }
}
</script>
```

ChildComponent.Vue

```
<template>
 <input type="text" v-model="slug" @input="wasEdited=true">
</template>

<script>
import Slug from "slug";

Slug.defaults.modes['pretty'] = {};
export default {
 name: "Child",
 props: {
  title: {
   type: String,
   required: true
  },
  initialSlug: {
   type: String,
   required: true
  }
 },
 data() {
  return {
   slug: this.initialSlug,
   wasEdited: false,
  }
 },
 methods: {},
 mounted() {
  this.slug = this.initialSlug
 },
 created() {
  this.slug = this.initialSlug
 },
}
</script>
```

I want the data I send to be written to the slug value.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is actually a simple process, you should `watch` it with a `watch`.We turn the initial Slug into a function and the incoming data is assigned to the desired slug value.

```
initialSlug: function () {
  this.slug = this.initialSlug
}
```

```
<template>
 <input type="text" v-model="slug" @input="wasEdited=true">
</template>

<script>
import Slug from "slug";

Slug.defaults.modes['pretty'] = {};
export default {
 name: "Child",
 props: {
  title: {
   type: String,
   required: true
  },
  initialSlug: {
   type: String,
   required: true
  }
 },
 data() {
  return {
   slug: '',
   wasEdited: false,
  }
 },
watch: {
  initialSlug: function () {
   this.slug = this.initialSlug
  }
 },
}
</script>
```